# Joomka K2 items in Json format not displaying anything

Tags: json, joomla, joomla-k2

I have my website www.kindheartz.com for which I want to see the json format data for any category items.
As an example I am trying to see json using 
http://kindheartz.com/index.php/free-classifieds/classifieds-by-category/donation?format=json

I have checked that my feeds are enabled for this category. But when I replace format=feed with format=json, I dont see any output.

Can you pls tell me what could be the issues? That would be really important for me to interface with third party items.

Rgds
Sapan

Comment: Do you have any modifications or formatting plugins which may change output?

Comment: I have not done any modifications...what plugins may change the output? I may have used a few but not sure which may cause this issue...Should I try to switch off all plugins?

Comment: Yes. Any plugin under system group can do this. This is the only option I can think of as like you are saying it should just work

Answer (score 0):

JSON output format available only using K2 editor. I have seen your website, it is using normal Joomla content editor (WYSIWYG editor) not K2 editor.

Transform all your content from notmal to K2, then check URL using ?format=json